# Corda How to identify the Account holding each state found in the vaultquery

Tags: corda

we use accounts and the states are associated with them.

In researching each type of state we use vaultService and externalIds to retrieve the states for each account.

**Example:**

**serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(contractStateType = State::class.java,
criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(externalIds = listOf(accountId)))**

But normally the application asks for data from a list of accounts, is it possible to retrieve states from a list of accounts and identify which account each returned state belongs to?

**serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(contractStateType = State::class.java,
criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(externalIds = listOf(accountId1,accountId2)))**

I know I can pass a list on externalIds as above, but can I identify the account from each state returned?

I thought about storing the account ID in the states, but it's not Corda's recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyManagementBackedAccountService` has many useful functions including `accountInfo(owningKey: PublicKey)`, see [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/3ef52aeef7d5d8e1a82ec637d321205fb032ce82/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/services/KeyManagementBackedAccountService.kt#L84-L86).

- If `holder` is of type `PublicKey`; you can pass its value and get the related `AccountInfo`.
- If `holder` is of type `AbstractParty`; you can pass `holder.owningKey`.

`KeyManagementBackedAccountService` has other functions to get `AccountInfo` by `name` or by `UUID`.

Btw, you can use `group by` in your query; so the returned results can be grouped by the `UUID` of the account, this way you can run `accountInfo(owningKey)` once per group. See examples on using `group by` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.5/node/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/vault/VaultQueryTests.kt) (search for `groupByColumns`).

Comment: When you say to check the holder, is it considering that the state has a property to store the holder? I say this because my state does not have a holder property. I did not put it because it is possible to recover through externalIds.
And from documentation (https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md#do-i-need-to-add-account-ids-to-my-state-objects) I thought not need account Id or AbstractParty representing the holder.
I'm wrong? Do I need a holder to identify?

Comment: How are you supposed to know that a state belongs to a certain account if you didn't add an attribute that signifies who's the owner/holder (whatever you want to call it)?

Comment: Read [here](https://training.corda.net/libraries/accounts-lib/#prepare-your-state)

Comment: Since the beginning of the project I found it strange not to identify the account holder, but I relied on the link I sent you.
You are right, thank you very much.